# AFNetworking: secure handshake no longer works after certificate renewal

Tags: ios, ssl, ssl-certificate, afnetworking

My app uses AFNetworking.

What type of certificate extension does AFNetworking look for?
I was given a .crt file by GeoTrust but I have read [here](http://initwithfunk.com/blog/2014/03/12/afnetworking-ssl-pinning-with-self-signed-certificates/) that AFNetworking specifically looks for .cer files.

I ask because my https in a browser works fine with my new certificate chain, and using a tool called SSLDetective I can see that the whole chain is trusted, but for some reason my app no longer accepts the bundle for a trusted handshake. Any other time I had issues, SSLDetective showed me that a part of the chain was not trusted. In this case, I can't seem to find anything wrong. Not much changed in my ssl certificate configuration other than overwriting the old key and crt files with the new files with the exact same name. Help is appreciated. Thanks!

**EDIT:**

I now know for sure that AFNetworking does use and automatically detects .cer files in the app bundle. I also know that the certificate attached in the bundle must match the same public key as the certificate on my web server. With public key pinning, AFNetworking simply extracts the public key from the local certificate and compares it to the one on the server. If the one on the server matches, it uses the server's certificate.

In my case, in the beginning, the keys did not match, but now I made sure that they do. The chain is still trusted and good according to SSLDetective. I downloaded a .cer version of the certificate from the server using SSLDetective and attached it to my app bundle. However, now that I know for sure the public keys match as well, I still can't seem to get a secure handshake. This question is somewhat related to the question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29156170/how-to-create-cer-file-for-afnetworking-to-be-used-in-ios-app-bundle).

Comment: Which pinning mode are you using? Based on your description, you should be using `AFSSLPinningModePublicKey`, instead of `AFSSLPinningModeCertificate`. Also, depending on your situation you might need to set `validatesCertificateChain` to `NO`.

Comment: I am using `AFSSLPinningModePublicKey`, but my server certificate chain isn't trusted by the certificate in my bundle. I have since gained this resource: `www.tls.so` and will be using it to further trouble shoot the problem in about a month. I will likely have to change the chain on the server.