# How to create .cer file for AFNetworking to be used in iOS app bundle

Tags: ios, ssl, ssl-certificate, afnetworking

I keep seeing disjointed accounts all over the web of what the .cer file is and how to generate it so that the app can properly communicate with the server via https.

To quote [this](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/1852) source, one person says:

> 1) You now need .cer files in your bundle for all certificates in the chain. So, at least, two certificate files must be present (your certificate and the root CA). In our case, we needed an intermediate as well.
>
> 2) These certificates must be in a particular order. Specifically, the certificate that certifies the host that you are communicating with must be first in the list of pinned certificates/keys. It doesn't look like the order of the rest of them matter. This is because AFSecurityPolicy uses the first object in the array to validate the host name.
>
> 3) The host validation fails for wildcard certificates if you are communicating with the root domain. For example, consider a certificate pointed at *.foo.com. If you are communicating with foo.com, the host check will fail because the host component counts will not match. I understand the need for this early optimization, but it fails before it even reaches the logic that specifically handles wildcard domains.

Official documentation backs that up [here](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/2.0.0/Classes/AFSecurityPolicy.html#overview).

I suppose that in order to generate this, one must cat the contents of their whole cert chain into a .cer file in a specific order. I remember seeing this posted somewhere, but can't seem to find it.

The question is, what is the undebatable method of creating a .cer file for AFNetworking?

UPDATE:

After more research, it seems to me that you simply take the .crt file and perform this on it:

`openssl x509 -in www.mydomain.com.crt -out www.mydomain.com.cer -outform der`

However, even after doing this and attaching the .cer to my app bundle, I get an error here:

```
+ (NSArray *)pinnedPublicKeys {
    static NSArray *_pinnedPublicKeys = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        NSArray *pinnedCertificates = [self pinnedCertificates];
        NSMutableArray *publicKeys = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[pinnedCertificates count]];

    for (NSData *data in pinnedCertificates) {
        SecCertificateRef allowedCertificate = SecCertificateCreateWithData(NULL, (__bridge CFDataRef)data);
        NSParameterAssert(allowedCertificate);
```

The error comes in at the last line. I suppose that in the preceding line where it attempts to assign an `allowedCertificate`, `SecCertificateCreateWithData` has the following description:

```
/*!
    @function SecCertificateCreateWithData
    @abstract Create a certificate given it's DER representation as a CFData.
    @param allocator CFAllocator to allocate the certificate with.
    @param certificate DER encoded X.509 certificate.
    @result Return NULL if the passed-in data is not a valid DER-encoded
    X.509 certificate, return a SecCertificateRef otherwise.
*/
```

Clearly it is returning a NULL, but I don't know why. My specific certificate is in the correct format. However, I did notice that there were other 'certificates' in the `pinnedCertificates` array, but I have no idea where it is getting them. Nor can I seem to find them or print them out. As far as I know, I only have the one in the app bundle, but it seems to show more than that.

The error generated from the assert on the last line is:

`*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid parameter not satisfying: allowedCertificate'`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using AFNetworking 2.5 the steps described below:

- Install valid certificate on your server
- Create .cer file `openssl x509 -in www_yourdomain_com.crt -out www_yourdomain_com.cer -outform der`
- Add .cer file to app project. IMPORTANT: Never add private key to your project!!!
- Setup AFNetworking secure policy

  ```
  - (AFSecurityPolicy *)securityPolicy {
     AFSecurityPolicy *securityPolicy = [AFSecurityPolicy policyWithPinningMode:AFSSLPinningModeCertificate];
     [securityPolicy setAllowInvalidCertificates:NO];
     [securityPolicy setValidatesDomainName:YES];
     return securityPolicy;
  }
  ```
- Set policy on network manager when making network call

  ```
   AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
   [manager setSecurityPolicy:[self securityPolicy]];
  ```

There's no need to manually load .cer file, if you're using `policyWithPinningMode:pinningMode` method to create security policy AFNetworking automatically pins them.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I don't think it's quite that simple because it still doesn't work. What about the intermediate certificate? Wouldn't that also need to be concatted into the .cer file? I am going to try that. ssldecoder.org is happy with my certificate chain, but my app crashes when simply just converting the site .crt to .cer.

Comment: It didn't work. AFNetworking doesn't seem to like something about the certificate file.

Comment: When using setup described above do you get specific error or it fails silently?

Comment: When looping through the pinned certificates (there are three), an exception is thrown when it hits the NSAssert of these two lines `SecCertificateRef allowedCertificate = SecCertificateCreateWithData(NULL, (__bridge CFDataRef)data);   
            NSParameterAssert(allowedCertificate);`

Comment: Documentation for SecCertificateCreateWithData: `@function SecCertificateCreateWithData
 @abstract Create a certificate given it's DER representation as a CFData.
    @param allocator CFAllocator to allocate the certificate with.
    @param certificate DER encoded X.509 certificate.
 @result Return NULL if the passed-in data is not a valid DER-encoded
    X.509 certificate, return a SecCertificateRef otherwise.` .....   allowedCertificate is null in this case, which would imply that the bundled cert has some kind of formatting issue.

Comment: I wonder if it has anything to do with the fact that I concatted the files using a text editor. Though I've read guides which say it's okay to do that.

Comment: I tried catting instead, and it works on the simulator but not on an actual device.....

Comment: hmm, i'm little confused in what you're trying to do, i think you're overcomplicate things.

Comment: I'm confused why are you trying to concatenate .cer files? Why do you manually pinning certificates? You don't need to do that unless you don't want to use AFNetworking implementation...  If you check AFNetworking implementation of policyWithPinningMode: it goes through app bundle finds all .cer files and pins them. If you're using AFNetworking for your networks calls the implementation i described above should work. I'm using this method in my app and i have multiple certs as well.

Comment: The reason I was trying to cat was because I wanted all the certificates contained in one .cer file, but I also just tried having all the separate .cer files in the app bundle, and it's still throwing errors. According to the documentation, this is the problem: `Return NULL if the passed-in data is not a valid DER-encoded X.509 certificate`... Therefore something must be wrong with the encoding or certificate type....

Comment: pin multiple certificates by adding them to the pinnedCertificates array of the security policy:

let policy: AFSecurityPolicy = AFSecurityPolicy(pinningMode: AFSSLPinningMode.Certificate)
            let path: String? = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("mycert", ofType: "cer")
            let keyData: NSData = NSData(contentsOfFile: path!)!

            policy.pinnedCertificates = [keyData]
            
If you have multiple certificates, add them all: [keyData1, keyData2 etc]